# What could be improved on this AD Cleanup Script

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have put together this script to clean inactive accounts: Disable, move them to another OU, have logging on these actions and at the end email a report to Helpdesk.

What can be improved on this?

```
$LogDate = Get-Date -f yyyyMMddhhmm
$SearchBase = "OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com"
$moveToOU = "OU=Inactive Accounts,OU=Disabled,DC=domain,DC=com"
$LogArray = @()
$PasswordAge = (Get-Date).AddDays(-29)
$log = "C:\temp\logdisable_$LogDate.log"

$DisabledUsers = (Get-ADUser -SearchBase $SearchBase -Properties samaccountname, name, distinguishedname -Filter {((lastlogondate -notlike "*") -or (lastlogondate -le $Passwordage)) -and (enabled -eq $True) -and (whencreated -le $Passwordage)})

if ($DisabledUsers -ne $null ) {
    foreach ($DisabledUser in $DisabledUsers) {
        try {
            Disable-ADAccount  -Identity $($DisabledUser.samaccountname)  -ErrorAction Stop -PassThru -Verbose -WhatIf
            $LogDate + " : " + $DisabledUser.samaccountname  + " AD account Disabled " | Out-File $log -Append
            Set-ADUser $DisabledUser -replace @{description = "InactiveUserAccount"} -ErrorAction Stop -PassThru -WhatIf
            $LogDate + " : " + $DisabledUser.samaccountname  + " Description Set as Inactive " | Out-File $log -Append
            Move-ADObject -Identity $($disableduser.SamAccountName) -TargetPath $moveToOU -WhatIf
        } catch {
            Write-Output "$LogDate $error[0] $($id)" | Out-File $log -append
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i think you want to ask this over at >> Code Review Stack Exchange — https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Removing the chicken switches comes to mind. And actually sending the e-mail.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I have never heard the term 'chicken switches', but I immediately knew what you were talking about, and that is an awesome name for `-whatif` :)

Comment: Why do you want it to be improved? What do you not like about it? If you know, you already almost have the answer, or can at least ask more specifically.